# scala regex multiple integers

Tags: scala

I have the following string that I would like to match on: `1-10 employees`.

Here is my regex statement `val regex = ("\\d+").r`

The problem I have is Im trying to find a way to extract the matched data and determine which value returned is bigger.

Here is what IM doing to process it

```
  def setMinAndMaxValue(currentCompany: CurrentCompany, matchIterator: Iterator[Regex.Match]): CurrentCompany = {
    var max = 0
    println(s"matchIterator - $matchIterator")
    matchIterator.collect {
      case regex(s: String) => println("found string")
      case regex(IntConv(x)) =>
        println("regex case")
        if (x > max) max = x
    }
    val (minVal, maxVal) = rangesForMaxValue(max)
    val newDetails = currentCompany.details.copy(minSize = Some(minVal), maxSize = Some(maxVal))
    currentCompany.copy(details = newDetails)
  }

object IntConv {
  def unapply(s : String) : Option[Int] = Try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  }.toOption.flatten
}
```

Comment: Your regex is incorrect (the first paren is outside the quotes). And what have you tried? Have you looked at the scaladoc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.matching.Regex ? The example there shows how to extract the data.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I do apologize, it's criminal of me to not include how I'm processing the data, I actually need a type before hand since the type from the iterator is a `Regex.Match`, and `toList` will return the same.

Comment: I don't know what your actual problem is now. What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I was confused by your original question, then you clarified it with code and now I have no idea what you're trying to do.

To extract numbers from a string, try this.

```
val re = """(\d+)""".r
val nums = re.findAllIn(string_with_numbers).map(_.toInt).toList
```

Then you can just `nums.min`, and `nums.max`, and whatever number processing you need.